# unable to drag-drop menu in appearance settings in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

We just upgraded to wordpress 4.5.2 and using genesis framework
We are unable to drag-drop menu in appearance settings. In fact we are unable to edit them
We tried disabling all the plugin (list given below) - but no success.

Please suggest what should we do..
List of Plugins

```
1) Allow PHP in Posts and Pages
2) Disqus Comment System
3) Remove Category URL
4) Simple 301 Redirects
5) Simplified Social Share
6) W3 Total Cache
7) Wordfence Security
```

Comment: look if it has an error through console or error log

Comment: yes in console it shows theses errors :- columns is not defined , e is undefined